# Only JRadioButton gets an import error(CheckBox possible). How do I fix it?

Tags: java, swing

Only JRadioButton gets an import error.

Others do not underline the error (CheckBox possible), but only the radio button gives an error.

Searching the question doesn't come up.

This has never happened before, but suddenly it doesn't.

help me please

(I tried changing the SE version, but it didn't work.)

- javaSE15, jdk16.0.1, window10
- error message : The import javax.swing.JRadioButton cannot be resolved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjGIx.png)

```
 package other;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import listener.Btn_ok_actionListener;
import object.Switch;

public class SettingWindow {
    
    private JFrame createFrame;
    private JLabel eastPortLabel;
    private JLabel westPortLabel;
    private JLabel southPortLabel;
    private JLabel northPortLabel;
    
    private JButton okButton;
    private JButton advButton;
    
    private JTextField eastPortTextField;
    private JTextField westPortTextField;
    private JTextField southPortTextField;
    private JTextField northPortTextField;
    
    private ButtonGroup eastPortBG;
    private ButtonGroup westPortBG;
    private ButtonGroup southPortBG;
    private ButtonGroup northPortBG;
    
    private JRadioButton eastPortRB_left;
    private JRadioButton eastPortRB_right;
    private JRadioButton westPortRB_left;
    private JRadioButton westPortRB_right;
    private JRadioButton southPortRB_up;
    private JRadioButton southPortRB_down;
    private JRadioButton northPortRB_up;
    private JRadioButton northPortRB_down;
    
    private DrawingWindow drawingWindow;
    private int type; // 0이면 수정, 1이면 생성
    private Switch s;
    
    // get
    public DrawingWindow get_drawingWindow() {
        
        return drawingWindow;
        
    }
    
    public int get_type() {
        
        return type;
        
    }
    
    public Switch get_switch() {
        
        return s;
        
    }
    
    public int get_eastPort() {
        
        return Integer.parseInt(eastPortTextField.getText());
        
    }
    
    public int get_westPort() {
        
        return Integer.parseInt(westPortTextField.getText());
        
    }
    
    public int get_southPort() {
        
        return Integer.parseInt(southPortTextField.getText());
        
    }
    
    public int get_northPort() {
        
        return Integer.parseInt(northPortTextField.getText());
        
    }
    
    //constructor, 크기는 대충 맞춤(감)
    public SettingWindow(DrawingWindow drawingWindow, int type, Switch s) {
        
        // set
        this.drawingWindow = drawingWindow;
        this.type = type;
        this.s = s; // 새로 생성인 경우는 null
        
        // constructor
        createFrame = new JFrame();
        
        eastPortLabel = new JLabel("east port");
        westPortLabel = new JLabel("west port");
        southPortLabel = new JLabel("south port");
        northPortLabel = new JLabel("north port");
        okButton = new JButton("ok");
        advButton = new JButton("advanced");
        
        eastPortTextField = new JTextField(5);
        westPortTextField = new JTextField(5);
        southPortTextField = new JTextField(5);
        northPortTextField = new JTextField(5);
        
        ButtonGroup eastPortBG = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup westPortBG = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup southPortBG = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup northPortBG = new ButtonGroup();
        
        JRadioButton eastPortRB_left = new JRadioButton("left");
        JRadioButton eastPortRB_right = new JRadioButton("right");
        JRadioButton westPortRB_left = new JRadioButton("left");
        JRadioButton westPortRB_right = new JRadioButton("right");
        JRadioButton southPortRB_up = new JRadioButton("up");
        JRadioButton southPortRB_down = new JRadioButton("down");
        JRadioButton northPortRB_up = new JRadioButton("up");
        JRadioButton northPortRB_down = new JRadioButton("down");
        
        // frame
        createFrame.setVisible(true);
        createFrame.setSize(330, 500); // 창 위에 배너 크기 27 추가
        createFrame.setResizable(false);
        createFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        createFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createFrame.setLayout(null);
        createFrame.add(eastPortLabel);
        createFrame.add(eastPortTextField);
        createFrame.add(westPortLabel);
        createFrame.add(westPortTextField);
        createFrame.add(southPortLabel);
        createFrame.add(southPortTextField);
        createFrame.add(northPortLabel);
        createFrame.add(northPortTextField);
        createFrame.add(okButton);
        createFrame.add(advButton);
        
        // button
        okButton.setBounds(180, 30 * 5 + 50 * 4, 100, 50);
        advButton.setBounds(50, 30 * 5 + 50 * 4, 100, 50);
        
        // label
        eastPortLabel.setBounds(10, 30, 60, 50);
        westPortLabel.setBounds(10, 30 * 2 + 50, 60, 50);
        southPortLabel.setBounds(10, 30 * 3 + 50 * 2, 60, 50);
        northPortLabel.setBounds(10, 30 * 4 + 50 * 3, 60, 50);
        
        // textField
        eastPortTextField.setBounds(80, 30, 180, 50);
        westPortTextField.setBounds(80, 30 * 2 + 50, 180, 50);
        southPortTextField.setBounds(80, 30 * 3 + 50 * 2, 180, 50);
        northPortTextField.setBounds(80, 30 * 4 + 50 * 3, 180, 50);
        
        // actionListener
        okButton.addActionListener(new Btn_ok_actionListener(this));
        
    }
    
    // method
    public void dispose() {
        createFrame.dispose();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). It should, for example, be possible to reproduce the error with just one `JLabel`, `JButton`, `JTextField`, `ButtonGroup`, `JRadioButton` etc.  Conversely, factor out 3rd party classes like `DrawingWindow` - they seem to have no relevance to the problem & prevent compilation.(3) 2) *"Others do not underline the error (CheckBox possible)"* What `CheckBox`? Various components are mentioned in the source, but `CheckBox` is not one of them. 3) .. It compiles cleanly here, ..

Comment: .. sans those 3rd party classes. 4) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 5) *"How do I fix it?"* I'd recommend tossing this code out and starting again, ***after*** having done the Java Tutorial trail related to making GUIs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't know why the problem was, but when I woke up it was resolved. (The red underline disappears) I tried restarting Eclipse once, but rebooting seems to have solved the problem. I hope you have a nice day.